# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘mgis’ in WSL based Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: installation, fenics

I want to use mgis.fenics python module and I have tried to build it from source using this [website](https://github.com/thelfer/MFrontGenericInterfaceSupport) and also used `git clone https://github.com/thelfer/tfel` as mentioned in [here](https://fenicsproject.discourse.group/t/problem-about-installing-mgis-fenics-python-module/3197) and compiled it using the instructions given on tfel installation site. I want to download mgis.fenics in WSL Ubuntu 22.04.

Procedure I tried :-
1. I downloaded the zip folder from [here](https://github.com/thelfer/MFrontGenericInterfaceSupport)
2. I extracted `MFrontGenericInterfaceSupport-master` into my C drive
3. mounted this folder in ubuntu using `cd /mnt/c/MFrontGenericInterfaceSupport-master`
4. type `cmake .`
5. type `cmake`
6. type `cmake -Denable-python-bindings=ON`
7. type `cmake -Denable-fenics-bindings=ON`
8. type `cmake -DPython_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS=3.10`
9. type `make`
10. type `make check`
11. type `sudo make install`
I tried using this [forum](https://fenicsproject.discourse.group/t/problem-about-installing-mgis-fenics-python-module/3197) on fenicsproject forum but unfortunately I am unable to solve the issue.
Error:

```
berserker@LAPTOP-S35CGO60:~$ python3
Python 3.10.6 (main, Nov 14 2022, 16:10:14) [GCC 11.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import mgis
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mgis'
>>>
```

After many attempts I am lost, and cannot figure out in which step I have made mistake.
Any guidance would be appreciated.
Thank You